# Can a variable template be mutated?

Tags: c++, templates, variable-templates

Today, someone presented me with code of the following form:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace example {
    template <typename T>
    T variable_template = T(42);
}

int main() {
    example::variable_template<int> = 10;
    std::cout << example::variable_template<int> << std::endl;
}
```

You can see it running here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a786c42b5204b0a

I expected this code to print 42, since 10 appears to be assigned to a temporary. Inside the namespace, there template is only a declaration (not an instantation), so there's no data to mutate inside of the namespace. Dispite that, it surprised me and printed 10 instead.

I would have also expected a warning on the assignment to a temporary, but that didn't happen either.

Is this undefined behaviour, is my understanding of templates flawed, or is something else going on?

Comment: _"I expected this code to print 42, since 10 appears to be assigned to a temporary."_ What temporary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Inside the namespace, there template is only a declaration (not an instantation), so there's no data to mutate inside of the namespace.

Not so!

> `[C++14: 14.7.2/6]:` An explicit instantiation of a class, function template, or variable template specialization is placed in the namespace in which the template is defined. *[..]*

When you have a class template `Foo`, and refer to an instantiation (say, `Foo<int>`), that instantiation exists just like a normal class, with the same scope as the template had.

There is nothing different with variable templates. When you refer to `example::variable_template<int>`, you "add" that variable to the scope containing the template.

**Your namespace `example` then contains a variable called `variable_template<int>`.**

---

> I would have also expected a warning on the assignment to a temporary, but that didn't happen either.

There are no temporaries here, aside from the `T(42)`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a relevant standard quote you could add? :)

Comment: @OMGtechy: Not really; I'd have to quote almost the entire chapter on Templates to disprove the fantasy that you have a temporary here :)

Comment: Well the one you jsut added was exactly what I was looking for, thanks again